# Post list displaying wrong in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-pages

I got a weird problem. My post list is displaying very weirdly in Chrome and Firefox.
In Internet Explorer it surprisingly works. I guess it easier to show the behaviour with images:
[image: This is Google Chrome]
This is in Google Chrome 66.0.3359.117
[image: This is Firefox]
Same in Firefox 57.0.4
[image: Internet Explorer]
And this is how it *should* look like in IE 11.0.9600.18977

I have never seen this. Has anyone else ever came across this problem?

Comment: Have you checked your console? Could be a JS error or perhaps some really weird CSS that only works in certain browsers.

Comment: @WebElaine No console error at all. I also tried to remove every backend styling, didn't help aswell.

Comment: What I just realized is when I change the view on the post list (i.e. set a tick at "Show Date"), it removes it instantly when clicking apply...

Comment: Probably a good idea to try basic WP troubleshooting: switch to a default theme and deactivate all your plugins, then re-enable them one by one to find out which one is causing the issue.